# How to use `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` with non rnn component

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have an architecture that uses an encoder before feeding into an RNN. The encoder input shape is `[batch, height, width, channels]` and the RNN input is shape `[batch, time, height, width, channels]`. I would like to feed the output from the encoder directly to the RNN, but this poses a memory issue. I would have to feed `batch*time ~= 3*100` (by reshaping) images into the encoder at one time. I know that `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` can leverage the `swap_memory`, and I would like to leverage this in the encoder too. Here is some condensed code:

```
#image inputs [batch, time, height, width, channels]
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch, time, in_sh[0], in_sh[1], in_sh[2]])

#This is where the trouble starts
#merge batch and time
inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [batch*time, in_sh[0], in_sh[1], in_sh[2]])
#build the encoder (and get shape of output)
enc, enc_sh = build_encoder(inputs)
#change back to time format
enc = tf.reshape(enc, [batch, time, enc_sh[0], enc_sh[1], enc_sh[2]])

#build rnn and get initial state (zero_state)
rnn, initial_state = build_rnn()
#use dynamic unrolling
rnn_outputs, rnn_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        rnn, enc,
        initial_state=initial_state,
        swap_memory=True,
        time_major=False)
```

The current method I am using is to a priori run the encoder on all my images (and save to disc), but I would like to perform dataset augmentation (to images) which is not possible once features have been extracted.

Comment: Why the down vote? (genuinely would like to know so I can improve my future questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has run into this issue. I made a wrapper derived from `RNNCell` that accomplishes what I need. The `model_fn` is a function that builds a subgraph using input and returns the output tensor. Unfortunately the output shape must be known (at least I couldn't get it to work otherwise).

```
class WrapperCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
    """A Wrapper for a non recurrent component that feeds into an RNN."""

    def __init__(self, model_fn, out_shape, reuse=None):
        super(WrapperCell, self).__init__(_reuse=reuse)
        self.out_shape = out_shape
        self.model_fn = model_fn

    @property
    def state_size(self):
        return tf.TensorShape([1])

    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return tf.TensorShape(self.out_shape)

    def call(self, x, h):
        mod = self.model_fn(x)
        return mod, tf.zeros_like(h)
```